# Sublime Text 3 (3103) stop highlighting .ctp files

Tags: cakephp, sublimetext3, sublimetext

Since I updated to the latest Sublime Text (revision 3103) the highlighting of .ctp (Used by CakePHP framework for templates) extension files has stopped working.

Any solution to this? They look totally plane now...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to:

> View > Syntax > Open all with current extension .. > PHP

[image]

Answer (score 4):

On the bottom right corner you will see the language:

[image]

When you click on it, at the top, you have an option that says: **Open all with current extension as...**  see second screenshot.

[image]